# Reduce loading time of website after minify / cache

Tags: wordpress, performance, caching, optimization

I have created website in wordpress and its about to go live from test server to live server.

Its simple website which having multiple plugins.

After completion of development we have enable cache and minify css/js from below pluign.

1)Better WordPress Minify

2)W3 Total Cache

I have been testing website on my test server which is basically shared server.

I have done test loading time on

1) pingdom

2) GTmatrix

3) google page speed tool

4) webpage test

Now i am getting website loading time which is vary from 6-10s, can you help me how further i can reduce loading time.(i have applied all .htaccess tricks and w3totalcache settings)

Below are parameter need to yet fix from gtmatrix and google page speed which i have tried but coudnt achive.

**GTmatrix:**

1) Y-slow -> Add expiry headers (list show minify js, css only (minify bunch only))

2) Page speed -> Leverage browser caching (list show minify js, css only (minify bunch only))

**Google page speed:**

1) Leverage browser caching (list show minify js, css only (minify bunch only))

Can anyone guide me further how can i,

1) How can i apply browser caching for already minify js and css?

2) There are multiple images from database which taking time to load on home page..how can i reduce loading time? (images are optimised already)

I have tried on check google but coudnt find anything suitable for me..

Please help.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

For #2, you can implement lazy load for images. Also, make sure you are specifying width and height of the images, and loading appropriate size images (i.e. not scaling down to display the required size).

Comment: I have implemented lazy loading, but it raise waring in pingdom like: This page makes 48 parallelizable requests to HOST-NAME Increase download parallelization by distributing these requests across multiple hostnames:

Comment: What's the link to the test server?

Answer (score 0):

The images might be optimized but are they as small (width x height) as they can be? You didn't load a larger image than you needed did you?

Comment: I have already optimised images and may page size is 1.1 MB, can you suggest me how can i further reduce page size? I have tried all google links and implemented but coudn't reduce yet..